# What is the difference between operators, functions, sequences and vectors?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, terminology, vectors

To me there is a hierarchy where vectors $\subset$ sequences $\subset$ functions $\subset$ operators

- All vectors are sequences, but not all sequences are vectors because
  sequences are infinite dimensional
- All sequences are functions, but not all functions are sequences
  because functions can do more than just map $\mathbb{N} \to A$ where
  $A$ is some set
- All functions are operators, but not all operators are functions
  because an operator can map functions to functions but function can only map numbers to numbers

Can someone check if my ideas are reasonable? Does there exist such a hierarchy?

Comment: You should switch vectors and sequences; vectors *can* be infinite dimensional (but may be finite), and sequences are *necessarily* countably infinite (by the usual terminology).  Also, you can have functions that act on functions, so really functions = operators.

Comment: I believe that you, in fact, can map functions to functions using functions via the composition of functions. i.e., $f:g \mapsto f \circ g$ where $f$, $g$, and $f \circ g$ are all functions. So I don't believe that logic works for showing functions $\neq$ operators, though it still may be true. I'm not sure.

Comment: there is no linear order between these concepts

Comment: To be sure though: by the usual definition, a "vector" is *not* necessarily just a list of numbers.  We can always *represent* the vectors in a vector space via lists of numbers, however.

Comment: Analysts restrict functions to having the reals or complex numbers as codomain. For other codomains, the term used is "map". Other fields use function for any codomain.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom ... a potentially uncountably long list :P

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I agree and where do matrices fall on the hierarchy :( matrices are finite dimensional operators?

Comment: No, consider the vector space containing all polynomials of indeterminate $x$, it's certainly infinite dimensional, consider the linear operators $\dfrac d {dx}$ or $\int$ with constant term zero, as they're linear operators they can be represented by a matrix, and that matrix must be infinite dimensional.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- *All vectors are sequences* **False** To a mathematician, a vector is an element of a vector space, and therefore need not be a sequence.  For example, the set of all continuous real valued functions on $[0,1]$ forms a vector space, and its elements are the 'vectors' of that space.  Since the most familiar example of a vector space is $\mathbb R^n$, we often use the word 'vector' to refer to *any* (normally finite) sequence of elements, even when the elements do not naturally form a vector space; but it is certainly incorrect to say that all vectors form sequences.
- *All sequences are vectors* **Also false**, but not for the reasons you have given.  If the terms of a sequence are elements of a field $F$, then that sequence is an element of the vector space, over $F$, of all sequences with terms in $F$, so it is a 'vector' in that sense.  However, if the terms of the sequence are sets with no extra structure, points of a metric space etc., then it doesn't make sense to say that the sequence is a vector.  *Note* that this has nothing to do with the sequence being infinite dimensional.  There exist infinite-dimensional vector spaces; indeed, *dimension* as a concept doesn't enter into the definition of a vector space at all: to be a vector, we onlyneed to be able to add and subtract with other vectors, and to be multiplied by scalars.  It happens that the simplest examples of vector spaces are finite-dimensional.
- *All sequences are functions* **True**, at least in the sense that we can view a sequence as a function from $\mathbb N$ into some set $A$.  Bear in mind, though, that this is but one *formalism* of the *idea* of a sequence; if we implemented the sequence in some other way - say, as the set of all its finite initial segments:
  $$
  \{(a_1), (a_1,a_2), (a_1,a_2,a_3),\dots\}
  $$
  or in any one of a number of possible ways that don't involve functions, *it would still be a sequence*; it just happens that the function definition is the most convenient.
- *All functions are sequences* Certainly **false**, as you correctly demonstrated.
- *All functions are operators* I'd say **false**, because I normally hear the word *operator* used to describe particular examples of functions: binary operators like $+,-,\times$ etc. or linear operators in functional analysis.  Then again, I wouldn't feel it was wrong to declare that 'operator' and 'function' should be synonyms.  However...
- *All operators are functions* This is definitely **true**; it is certainly not the case that functions can only map numbers to numbers: in mathematics, a function can map from any set to any other set.

Sorry if some of that went over your head.  The point I'm trying to make is that the concepts 'vector', 'sequence' and 'function' come from different areas in mathematics (though of course they are used together all the time), while 'function' and 'operator' are very similar words (with 'function' being the more fundamental and universal term in case of doubt).  So there is no such hierarchy in mathematics.  But well done for exploring and trying to find patterns; keep it up and you'll discover some really beautiful ones.

Comment: Sorry this is from my simplistic college non-math major interpretation, for example, a vector $x = (a_1, a_2)$, a sequence is $(x_n) = \{x_1,x_2,x_3......\}$, a function is $f(x) = sin(x)$ a set consisting of infinitely many elements, an operator $A = \int$ maps $f(x) = sin(x)$ to some other function - So definitely no rigorous math understanding here

Comment: And also you first learn about vectors in linear algebra, then learn about sequence in real analysis, then you learn about function and finally you learn about operators/ integral transforms - so it is also related to how the curriculum is set up

Comment: @FemaleTank Yeah, I understand; I just wanted to make you aware of how things stand in the field of rigorous mathematics, and to show you why the linear relationship you proposed does not in fact hold.

Answer (score 3):

1. Vectors are not sequences. A vector is an element of a vector space; identifying vectors with tuples of numbers requires a choice of basis of the vector space. (For example, when we write elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as $n$-tuples of real numbers, we're implicitly using the standard basis $(1, 0, \dots, 0), \dots, (0, \dots, 0, 1)$.)
2. As you said, a sequence with values in a set $A$ is a function $\mathbb{N} \to A$. Not all functions are sequences, because functions can have domains other than $\mathbb{N}$.
3. "Operator" can have multiple meanings; it's often used as a synonym of "linear map between vector spaces", or "linear map from a vector space to itself". In any case, all operators are functions.
4. It's not true at all that "functions can only map numbers to numbers". One can talk about functions between any two sets. (Also, "number" isn't a precise mathematical term — it's an informal term for a long list of mathematical objects, such as integers, real numbers, complex numbers, $p$-adic numbers, ordinal numbers, cardinal numbers, quaternions, etc.)
5. A matrix is a finite rectangular array of numbers. (Since I just talked about how "number" is a vague word, I guess I should remark that you can replace "number" by "element of a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29)" if you want a precise statement.) Matrices show up in many contexts, but one of the most fundamental is this: given a linear map between finite-dimensional vector spaces $f: V \to W$, if we choose a basis for $V$ and for $W$, we can represent $f$ in this basis, giving a bijective correspondence between linear maps $V \to W$ and matrices of the appropriate size. Under this correspondence, function composition corresponds to matrix multiplication. So, you can think of matrices as "finite-dimensional operators between vector spaces *with a choice of basis*". (But don't forget that they can also represent other things, such as bilinear forms or systems of linear equations, to name a couple.)

Comment: $\mathbb R^n$ is defined to be the set of all $n$-tuples of real numbers, which we can endow with a vector space structure, so we are not really choosing a basis, implicitly or otherwise, when we write an element of $\mathbb R^n$ as a tuple.  Of course, if we said 'let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional real vector space and then started writing elements of $V$ as tuples, we would be implicitly choosing a basis.  One way of defining a basis of an ($n$-dimensional, real) vector space is: an isomorphism from that vector space to $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize the comments:

The concepts in their general meaning do not admit a linear hierarchy.

- Vectors are elements of a *vector space*. For example, $\mathbb R^n$,  the set of $\mathbb R$ valued function over a non empty set $X$, $\mathbb R$ as $\mathbb Q$ vector space.
- Sequences are function form $\mathbb N$ into any non empty set $X$. If $X$ is a $K$ vector space, then the $X$ valued sequences become a $K$ vector space by point wise operations.
- Functions are the most general concept. Sequences are functions. Particular function spaces are vector spaces in a natural way.
- Operators are functions between vector spaces (usually over the same scalar field).

Answer (score 1):

A vector is an object of a vector space that obeys the usual vector space properties.

A sequence is a function from the natural numbers to some set.

If $X$ is a set, and $Y$ is a set, a function is a subset of $X \times Y$ such that for $(x,y), (x,y') \in X \times Y$, we have $y = y'$.

An operator is a function from a vector space to another vector space.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors are not sequences. They can be represented in some cases by finite sequences (as Omnomnomnom has pointed out). But in general a vector is any elements of a vector space, and a vector space is any set where you can add and multiply by scalars. All sequences are vectors, because they form a vector space. All functions from a fixed set into a field also form a vector space over that field, so they are also vectors. Operators are just functions from the cross-product of a set with itself into the same set (binary operators that is). If that set is a field, then they too are vectors in a vector space.

But if the sets in question are not fields, then you don't get vectors. The relationships here are much richer than your schema comprehends.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to think of each as its own type of object, but where some types can be naturally converted into others (similar to type conversion in computer programming).  Some of the conversions faithfully translate all of the information, some are reversible, and others lose part of the information.