# How can sequences satisfy vector space properties? If sequence is not a vector.

Tags: functional-analysis

How can sequences satisfy vector space properties? If sequence is not a vector.

An example semantic problem occurs, when one needs to find a zero element or zero $\bar{0}$. In order to do this for sequences one'd intuitively define $\{a_n\}, a_n=0 \forall n$ as the zero element. However, this is a sequence, not a vector.

As to why the treating of sequences as vectors may not be intuitive:

[What is the difference between operators, functions, sequences and vectors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397576/what-is-the-difference-between-operators-functions-sequences-and-vectors)

Comment: This is too vague.  One sequence is just a single object, so it can't be a vector space (or at least not a very interesting one).  It could, of course, be an element in a vector space.

Comment: @lulu Okay. My question is how can one display vector spaces properties on sequences, since sequences don't have addition, scalar multiplication.

Comment: Sure they do.  $\{a_n\}+\{b_n\}=\{a_n+b_n\}$ and $\lambda \times \{a_n\}=\{\lambda a_n\}$.

Comment: @mavavilj You can certainly add sequences pointwise: $a_n+b_n$. The same goes for scalar multiplication.

Comment: @lulu Intuitively yes, but I couldn't find the formal definition for refreshing.

Comment: i just wrote out the formal definition.  Where's the problem?

Comment: @lulu Whether it's regarded "standard" sequence property. Or whether you just invented it.

Comment: Well, it's entirely natural so why not?  Certainly the vector space of formal power series over a field is entirely standard, and this is the same thing.

Comment: @lulu Also when doing those operations, then that's likening the sequences to vectors, no?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you are after here.  If you have a field $\mathbb F$, then the set of sequences of elements in $\mathbb F$ form a vector space in an obvious way.  Any such sequence is then, of course, a vector in that vector space.

Comment: @lulu As far as treating sequences as vectors is obvious? One must find a zero element, which is often written as a vector. But one has sequences, or are they also vectors then?

Comment: The zero vector in this case is obviously the sequence $\{a_n\}$ with $a_n=0\,\forall n$.  You can write it however you like.

Comment: @lulu https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397576/what-is-the-difference-between-operators-functions-sequences-and-vectors

Comment: A sequence is just a function from the natural numbers to real numbers.

Comment: That post doesn't make sense either.  Definitions are just that, definitions.  The fact that we can define a vector space whose elements are sequences doesn't obligate you in any way.

Comment: An element of a vector space is called a vector. It may or may not have any resemblance to 'vectors'

Comment: @ShubhamJohri You mean that one constructs vector spaces over sequences, but after one has done them, then the elements become vectors? Or that these "semantically" remain still sequences, as in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space

Comment: Yes. Consider the set of functions with domain $\Bbb R$. They form a vector space and each function is called a vector even though none of them is actually a 'vector' like $(1,2,3)$.

Comment: What is your definition of a vector?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Vectors are elements of vector spaces. The confusion lies in that some references such as: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorSpace.html give e.g. the zero element def. as "exists $0$", whereas I've read some other sources use the wording "exists zero *vector* $\bar{0}$". But if one hasn't shown $E$ as vector space yet, then it's odd to argue why it would have a zero vector.

Comment: $\vec0,\mathbf0,\bar0$ are all shorthand mathematical notations for the zero vector. There is no semantic issue there. The zero vector can take different forms for different vector spaces.

Comment: For the vector space $V=\Bbb R^3,\vec0=(0,0,0)$. For the vector space $W$ of functions from $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, the zero vector is the zero function, $\vec0:=f(x)=0$. You can call the zero vector of $V$ as $\vec0_V$ and that of $W$ as $\vec0_W$ to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

You should carefully read the accepted answer of the question you linked to. That question was based on misconceptions, and it seems yours is too.

Consider the following passage from [that answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1397587):

> If the terms of a sequence are elements of a field $F,$ then that sequence is an element of the vector space, over $F,$ of all sequences with terms in $F,$ so it is a 'vector' in that sense.

The comments on that answer indicate that the problem is pedagogical: the early levels of instruction in math (which is all most people ever see)
give only limited perspectives into the field of mathematics.
It is likely that someone will see only finite-dimensional vector spaces,
or at least that only the finite-dimensional vector spaces will be identified as vector spaces.

The more general, advanced viewpoint is that anything that satisfies the formal definition of a vector space is a vector space, and its members are vectors.
There are various ways to state a formal definition of *vector space*
([here is an example](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorSpace.html)),
but they generally admit the same models of vector spaces,
for example sequences of elements of a field $F$ as described in the passage above.

This may not be intuitive at first. Part of an education in mathematics is gaining experience with the application of the definition of the term *vector space*
until applications like this *become* intuitive.

Comment: The confusion may not come from "elementary mathematics" but instead from  "physics", where the term **vector** is used with their special connotations.  Even in more advanced physics, when they use a Hilbert space, its elements are not called "vectors" but something else, such as "states".

Comment: @GEdgar True, and reading even further in the discussion of the earlier question, even some fields of higher mathematics differ in how they use certain terms. So it really would depend on which communities one has been exposed to. On the other hand, after one has seen definitions get broadened or narrowed a few times I suspect it gets easier to get past stumbling blocks such as the one we seem to have here (whatever its exact nature is).

Answer (score 0):

A similar confusion arises in Toplogy. Given any topology on a given set such as the real numbers, then the members of that topology are called "open" by definition of toplogical space. However, unlike open intervals in the usual topology of the real numbers, there is nothing "open", except the name, about the open sets of a topological space. It is simply a matter of terminology, not ontology.

In the same way, given any vector space, the elements of the space as called "vectors" by definition of vector space. There need not be any connection with what is usually called a vector in Euclidean spaces. The name "vector" here merely means that the object is a member of a particular set which is equipped with the operations of vector addition and scalar multiplication and the operations satisfy certain properties. It is entirely possible that the objects of the vector space may have different operations and names in another context. This does not contradict their status as vectors also.